# Game in browser. Where process events: in frontend or in backend?

Tags: javascript, java

I develop simple game for browsers. In this game main is shuffling quadrates (5x5).
When user press some buttons (WASD or arrow buttons) state of quadrates is changing.
I try to choose between frontend (`javascript`) and backend(`java`) for processing key events.

1. **Frontend** (Javascript)
   In this case key events will be processed in client browser. So it will be fast.
   But, will it safe? Can user somehow change my JS code/file on his own???
2. **Backend** (Java)
   In this case key events will be processed on server.
   Will it fast enough? In this case I will transfer data via ajax request.

I will be glad to hear which approach is better and why? Which approach is the most common?

**PS**. I know Java better than Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide on the frontend, your user can of course change the JavaScript and manipulate it in any way they want. If this is absolutely not wanted by you you can either do it in your backend, or, what I would suggest in a case like this, do it on both sides. Meaning frontend for the user-experience and also on the backend via ajax call. The result can be displayed immediately from the frontend code, but the definitive result comes from the server. The logic to implement such a behavior is not simple, but may be worth it. Usually such an approach is used when the user can change resources for other users as well as for themselves. Here the immediate response in the frontend gives the user a good UI-Experience, while the server can still reject conflicting edits. In your case you just need some validation code.

But if this is just a game, why not do it only frontend? Do you care if a user manipulates this? Or is there a server side component anyway?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that if you're worried about the security of your code the best way to completely avoid that is to write it in backend.  Here's a full rundown of some of the other things you probably should take into consideration:

**Speed:**
Like you identified in your post, front-end code will almost always be faster.  This is in large part because network requests take time to get a response.  If you decide to go with a backend implementation you can try to make it faster by reducing the size of your packets, but unless you start looking into professional hosting you'll be limited by your host internet connection speed and you'll *always* be limited by your client's connection speed.

**Server Load:**
Another thing to consider is how powerful your server is.  If it has to make all the decisions of whether a particular move is legal or not, will it be able to keep up?  For a small project this won't be too big of an issue, but it would be good practice to start keeping this in your mind.  As long as your game logic isn't massive then having it all in the front-end code would help lower the demands placed on your server and network connection.

**Security:**
Like I said above, implementing all your logic server-side is the best way to keep your logic code out of the hands of would-be hackers, but there's a bit more to the story here.  How motivated would someone be to cheat on your game?  Is there any reward or high-score status they would want to get?  If your game is multiplayer or there is any sort of reward for winning (other than just a “you win" screen or some cool animation/sounds) then I would implement it server-side.  If not then I don't see a reason to be worried about code security, because there's a far lessened incentive to cheat.  Also if there's no high-score list or any other way that one player could know the outcome of another player's game, then what effect would their cheating have on you or on the other players?  In most cases: nothing.  The cheater can feel good about their being “smart" or whatever it is they want, they may even brag to their friends about it, but in most cases it doesn't matter to the integrity of your game as a whole because they didn't actually play it: they hacked it.  They lose the experience of winning a *game* in favor of the experience of hacking *code*.  Your average player wouldn't try this, and a lot of those who do won't continue to find pleasure in it because there is no longer a point to playing.

**Overall:**
Either way would probably be fine for a small game.  Ultimately it's up to you; make a decision based on what your personal goals are with this project.  But there is one more thing to be said . . . Your options are not merely limited to server-side or client-side.  You could always try to implement both.  This would not be a project for the faint-of-heart beginner, and it would probably involve some careful planning and dedicated debugging, but it would give great advantages in a lot of areas.  You could have client-side logic that instantly responds to your user's actions and provides the speed of not relying solely on network requests, but at the same time have it send asynchronous requests to the server to validate every user action.  At the end of the game the server compares its simulated result with the client's result, and if they match (and no rules were broken) the game is valid and can be scores.  You'd get good speed, and good security.  Is there any downside to this?  Other than the fact that it would be more difficult and involved to implement it would also produce more load for your server, as each move would have to be validated along with the end result.  But if you have a good enough server, this likely is the “best of both worlds" solution.